# UI Automation inserting text into textfield containing text

Tags: ios-ui-automation

I have been using setValue() for inserting text into text fields, but setValue() replaces any text that is already in the text field. I want to add more text to the existing text in the text field. Is there a way to do so?

I am using xcode 4.5, and tuneup for automation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think UIAutomation is not very much fully developed to have exclusive functions for each operations, its still under development and till the date they provided functions which are almost complete.
So...There is no any function provided by UIAutomation to append text in textField. But this can be solved by programming code like:

pseudo code:

1. take existing value in temporary string
2. append new/extra test using '+' operator
3. setValue with new formed string.

Hope you get that.